# Vuejs this.$refs.file1.files[0] rasies an error cannot read property '0' of undefined at VueComponent.filesChange

Tags: vue.js

The problem is when I tried to console out the attached file in the  with this.$refs.file1.files raises as files is undefined. But if I print out this.$refs.file1 shows html object  with its files attribute inside. 
The source code is attached below and I would appreciate for your answer.

The HTML part of the vuejs
[image]

The method or the handler function for the file change. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

the problem is that your `input[type=file]` is into a `v-for`. So there is probably more than just one `$refs['file1']`.

You should work with the targeted input element for your event:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" name="myFile" @change="fileChanged">
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    fileChanged (e) {
        console.log(e.target.files)
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71tw6zu0/

Answer (score 3):

I changed the code to this one  and works perfectly.

[image]

```
filesChange(fieldName, fileList) {
    console.log (fileList)
    if (!fileList.length) return;
    this.files[0]=fileList[0];
  }
```